# What is the correct term for a "coalescing" event queue?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Say I have a queue of "event" objects, where, each object has an "event type" and some kind of data field. In C++ it could be like this:

```
enum class EventType
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

struct Event
{
     EventType type;
     std::string message;
};
```

Say, I wanted a queue of these events, and I want the queue to have the following properties:

- When an event is pushed to the queue, any existing events of the same `EventType` are removed. Therefore when an event is popped from the queue it is always the most *recently added* instance of its `EventType`
- Events of *different* `EventType` are popped in the order they were pushed. (`pop()` would not expect any arguments).

The queue is therefore FIFO with respect to `Event` and `LIFO` with respect to `EventType`.

**Example:**

The following events are pushed to the queue (letter is event type, number is instance number)

```
A1 A2 C1 C2 C3 B1 B2 A3
```

If pop() is then called 3 times, the items returned in order would be

```
C3 B2 A3
```

Is there a name for this type of data structure and are there any examples of implementations?

Comment: So a `pop` needs to be specified with an event type?

Comment: I'm maybe missing something, but won't your requirements mean that there's exactly 0 or 1 events of a given type in the queue? How do you imagine the signature of the function Pop() to look like? Do you specify an event type?

Comment: sounds like a combination of a priority queue and an evicting queue (with custom logic of course)

Comment: The Qt [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#) talks about 'compressing' events. But it is not immediately clear if this also applies to non-adjacent events.

Comment: [boost::bimap<unordered_set<EventType>, list_of<Event>>](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html) may be a good base data structure.

Comment: @acraig5075 `pop` does not need to be specified with an event type. It should always return the next event in the queue according to FIFO order. Otherwise we have a map not a queue.

Comment: @divinas Yes, there would always be exactly 0 or 1 events of a given type. But imagine we have 100+ event types. A queue would have these in FIFO order with `pop()` returning the first oldest items first.

Comment: @BiagioFesta yup. I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: @kmdreko I think you are right "evicting queue" is a useful concept here. Thanks.

Comment: Before your edit, you said you can delete the elements of same `EventType`. Is this property still hold?

Comment: After your edit, the question become ambiguous. You should remove the ambiguity with a more formal description, or, at least, some examples.
E.g., What happen in the case I push `A1 ; B1 ; C1 ; A2` ? For the first rule `A2` is before `A1`, but the order for the second rule? You have two cases here (considering type `A` as first insertion): `A2->A1->B1->C1` or `B1->C1->A2->A1` (considering type `A` as last insertion). That is not specified...

Comment: @BiagioFesta OK, I've now updated with a disambiguation and example. Is it clear now?

Comment: Better thanks, I will try to implement a simple example

Answer (score 0):

---

*Disclaimer: Design of very efficient data structures it is something strictly related to the domain (architecture) and the context of the data. The following solution aims to be theoretically efficient for the general case. See final considerations for more details.*

---

#### Structure Design

The idea is simple.

Keep an *underlying data structure* which represents the *queue*.

Every time a new event is inserted, check if the type is already present. In that case, we can delete that element. In such a way, we maintain the first property (only one instance per type, and that implies we always pop the most-recent for that type).

Finally, we insert the new instance at the end of the queue. Therefore, we keep the second property.

---

#### An example of simple Implementation

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

class QueueWithAGoodName {
 public:
  using reference = Event&;

  void push(Event event) {
    if (const auto finder =
            std::find_if(queue_.begin(),
                         queue_.end(),
                         [eventType = event.type](const Event& event) {
                           return event.type == eventType;
                         });
        finder != queue_.end()) {
      queue_.erase(finder);
    }
    queue_.push_back(std::move(event));
  }

  reference front() { return queue_.front(); }

  void pop() { queue_.pop_front(); }

 private:
  std::list<Event> queue_;
};
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/qlkTbZ)

---

#### Considerations and Analysis

- For my example, I have used a `std::list` as the *underlying data structure*. Indeed, a `std::list` is handy in case you have frequent deletion "in the middle". Moreover, after deletion, iterators are not invalidated. That's a good property in case we want to improve our queue.
- `QueueWithAGoodName::push` has a runtime time complexity: `O(N)` (because we apply a linear scan for finding the type). Where `N` is the size of the queue.
- `QueueWithAGoodName::pop` and `QueueWithAGoodName::front` are `O(1)`.

#### Further Considerations

- For such type of data structure, there is an important property. We have one instance per type. That implies `N` (the size of the queue) is upper-bounded by the number of `EventType`s.
- If the number of event types is limited, several considerations can be applied because (for common architectures) the runtime complexity `O(N)` can be approximate as `O(1)`. In such case, `std::vector` as underlying data-structure is probably more efficient because of caches.
- In the simple example I've reported, `push` is `O(N)`. In case you have several types of `EventType`s you can make the data structure more efficient in the push operation. In short, you can use an auxiliary `std::unordered_map<EventType, list::iterator>` (that is, an *hash map*) to avoid the linear search. After erasing, `std::list` does not invalidate iterators, so the hash table remains consistent.

Comment: Thanks for this. It answers very well the part of the question that asks for a reference implementation. Can we think of a good name for this type of queue? `TypeEvictingFIFO` ?